# What is this strange notation in the output of Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: roots, wolfram-alpha

For some reason I need to find the values of two positive integers $k$ and $x$ such that:

$$
k x^3 (2 x + 1)^3>2 (k + 1) (x + 1)^2 (2 x^4 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^2 + 2 x + 1).
$$

[Inputting this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=k%20x%5E3%20(2%20x%20%2B%201)%5E3%3E2%20(k%20%2B%201)%20(x%20%2B%201)%5E2%20(2%20x%5E4%20%2B%202%20x%5E3%20%2B%203%20x%5E2%20%2B%202%20x%20%2B%201)) in Wolfram Alpha gives the following strange result (among others):

> $$ k>1, x>Root[\#1^6 (4 k - 4) - 12 \#1^5 + \#1^4 (-12 k - 18) + \#1^3
> > (-19 k - 20) + \#1^2 (-16 k - 16) + \#1 (-8 k - 8) - 2 k - 2\&, 2] $$

What does this mean? What is the role of the symbols $\#$ and $\&$?

Comment: `Root[f, k]` denotes the $k$-th exact root of the polynomial function $f$. And Mathematica supports inline construction of anonymous functions using `#` and `&`. For instance, `#1^6&` is the same as the function `f[x_]:=x^6;`

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you, I understand it better now. But it's still not clear to me what $\&$ does. Isn't it sufficient to use $\#1^6$ to denote $x^6$?

Comment: @SangchulLee One more question: according to the definition of `Root[f, k]`, the result is related to the *second* root of the above equation (here $k=2$). But what defines the *order* of the roots? There is no clear definition as to what makes a certain root the *second* root?

Comment: I am not sure why `Root` function is designed in that way. It seems to accept polynomial function as an argument, and the operator `&` is needed to construct an anonymous function. Also, I agree that the order of the roots must be arbitrary somehow, and I guess that they are determined by some internal algorithm.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @SangchulLee If you post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a command like

RegionPlot[
 $k x^3 (2 x + 1)^3 - 
   2 (k + 1) (x + 1)^2 (2 x^4 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^2 + 2 x + 1) > 0$, {$k$, 0, 
  10}, {$x$, 0, 10}]

You will obtain an useful plot

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tip, however this does not answer my question.